# Adapt focal length in pixel to new image resolution

Tags: image, opencv, parameters, resolution

I am using a stereo camera to process the images in order to work with point clouds. I am using a method proper to the PCL library to create those point clouds (shame on me) but anyway, here is my problem: The camera sensor resolution is 1/3.2" 752x480, it has a baseline of 12cm and a focal length of 2.17 mm.

I managed to convert the focal length to pixels and pass it as well as the other parameters to the function that I am using to create the point clouds. It could be faster if I was reducing the initial image resolution: I would like to pass from 752x480 to 263x168 (35% of the initial resolution) in order to process the clouds faster. I am currently stucked on this problem: How to transform the previous parameters to adapt them to this new resolution. I checked the OpenCV camera calibration documentation but I didnt find what i was looking for (maybe I didnt looked into it properly).

could you help me on this?

thank you in advance

edit:
What I tried to do:

```
float focal_pixel = (FOCAL_METERS / SENSOR_WIDTH_METERS)*img.cols;// times 0.35 ?
//coordinates of the principal points
float hori_c_pp = (img.cols - 1) / 2;
float vert_c_pp = (img.rows - 1) / 2;
```

the focals in meters as well as the sensor width in meters are constant variables. I need those parameters to create a point cloud. As far as I am concerned I think that the problem comes from the focal in pixels,
because I am missing a lot of point if I am just applying it like this and My point cloud results just in a few lines of points not relevent at all.

functions used

```
virtual void 
      compute (unsigned char* ref_img, unsigned char* trg_img, int width, int height);

      /** \brief stereo processing, it computes a disparity map stored internally by the class
        *
        * \param[in] ref point cloud of pcl::RGB type containing the pixels of the reference image (left image)
        * the pcl::RGB triplets are automatically converted to grayscale upon call of the method
        * \param[in] trg point cloud of pcl::RGB type containing the pixels of the target image (right image)
        * the pcl::RGB triplets are automatically converted to grayscale upon call of the method
        */




getPointCloud (float u_c, float v_c, float focal, float baseline, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud,  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::RGB>::Ptr texture);

      /** \brief computation of a pcl::RGB cloud with scaled disparity values
        * it can be used to display a rescaled version of the disparity map by means of the pcl::ImageViewer
        * invalid disparity values are shown in green
        * Note: the "compute" method must have been previously called at least once in order for this function
        * to have any effect
        * \param[out] vMap output cloud
        */
```

Comment: You say you manage the input parameters for the full resolution. This means know the formulas. What prevents you to apply them with the reduced resolution ??

Comment: Because so far I have been using the following formula to calculate the full resolution focal pixel: focal_pixel=(focal_meters/sensor_width_meter) * resolution_width. I tried to adapt this formula to the new width of my new resolution but it doesnt seem to work this way

Comment: What are the old and new values ? The second should be 35% of the first. And what tells you that "it doesn't seem to work" ?

Comment: I edited my post to show you what I tried so far

Comment: How is using PCL a shame on you?

Comment: This is not enough. You don't even mention the function(s) you are calling.

Comment: added. Nallath, this is irony, I say that because opencv can be more effective for creating pcls